# Binary tree-- strcmp - valgrind error

Tags: c++, tree, binary-tree

I have a problem with strcmp function. After compilation there are no warnings, but when I use valgrind it shows serveral errors exactly on line where strcmp is.

It is a binary tree which is implemented recursively.

Do you have any tips?

```
    int BSInsert(bStromPtr *tree, char* key, TSymbol symbol){

    int res;

if(*tree  == NULL){
    *tree = malloc(sizeof(struct bStrom));
    if(*tree == NULL){
        return ERR_CODE_OTH;
    }

    (*tree)->data = malloc(sizeof(struct symbol));
        if((*tree)->data == NULL){
            return ERR_CODE_OTH;
        }

        (*tree)->key = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char) * 2);
        if((*tree)->key == NULL){
            return ERR_CODE_OTH;
        }

    (*tree)->lptr = malloc(sizeof(struct bStrom));  //treba to?
            if((*tree)->lptr == NULL){
            return ERR_CODE_OTH;
        }
    (*tree)->rptr = malloc(sizeof(struct bStrom));
            if((*tree)->rptr == NULL){
            return ERR_CODE_OTH;
        }

        (*tree)->lptr = NULL;
        (*tree)->rptr = NULL;
        (*tree)->key = key;
        (*tree)->data->type = symbol->type;   
        (*tree)->data->name = symbol->name;
        (*tree)->data->isFunction = symbol->isFunction;   
        //(*tree)->data->type = symbol->isDeclared;   


}


//printf("%d  \n", &(*tree)->key );
res= strcmp( *(tree->key), key );


if(res < 0){

         BSInsert(&((*tree)->rptr),key, symbol);
    }
    else if(res > 0){

         BSInsert(&((*tree)->lptr),key, symbol);
    }
    else{

        (*tree)->data = symbol;
    }
return ERR_code_succ;
}


Let me know if you need more info thanks
```

Comment: We need to see a lot more code. Exactly how is `key` initialized? And what does the code right before this call to `strcmp` look like? (Is it the first access to `*tree`?)

Answer (score 0):

Here is whole function.. I dont know whether that will help

```
int BSInsert(bStromPtr *tree, char* key, TSymbol symbol){

    int res;

if(*tree  == NULL){
    *tree = malloc(sizeof(struct bStrom));
    if(*tree == NULL){
        return ERR_CODE_OTH;
    }

    (*tree)->data = malloc(sizeof(struct symbol));
        if((*tree)->data == NULL){
            return ERR_CODE_OTH;
        }

        (*tree)->key = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char) * 2);
        if((*tree)->key == NULL){
            return ERR_CODE_OTH;
        }

    (*tree)->lptr = malloc(sizeof(struct bStrom));  //treba to?
            if((*tree)->lptr == NULL){
            return ERR_CODE_OTH;
        }
    (*tree)->rptr = malloc(sizeof(struct bStrom));
            if((*tree)->rptr == NULL){
            return ERR_CODE_OTH;
        }

        (*tree)->lptr = NULL;
        (*tree)->rptr = NULL;
        (*tree)->key = key;
        (*tree)->data->type = symbol->type;   
        (*tree)->data->name = symbol->name;
        (*tree)->data->isFunction = symbol->isFunction;   
        //(*tree)->data->type = symbol->isDeclared;   


}


//printf("%d  \n", &(*tree)->key );
res= strcmp( *(tree->key), key );


if(res < 0){

         BSInsert(&((*tree)->rptr),key, symbol);
    }
    else if(res > 0){

         BSInsert(&((*tree)->lptr),key, symbol);
    }
    else{

        (*tree)->data = symbol;
    }
return ERR_code_succ;
}
```

Comment: How is it called? What is `key`? Is it a constant? (Like `BSInstert(tree, "a", symbol)`)? Does it point to memory guaranteed to continue to exist? (If not, what do you save it?)

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to tell from just what you've shown, but clearly something is horribly wrong with the way `key` is being initialized:

```
    (*tree)->key = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char) * 2);

     ...
    (*tree)->key = key;
```

So, first you allocate some memory, then you forget about that allocation entirely and set `key` equal to an input parameter to your function. That can't possibly be right.

Perhaps you meant to copy something into that memory you allocated?

```
(*tree)->rptr = malloc(sizeof(struct bStrom));
...
(*tree)->lptr = malloc(sizeof(struct bStrom));
...
    (*tree)->lptr = NULL;
    (*tree)->rptr = NULL;
```

And, again, you allocate some memory and then just leak the allocated memory. I have no idea what you're trying to do here. Are `rptr` and `lptr` supposed to point to new objects? If so, why set them to `NULL`? Or are they not supposed to point to anything? If so, why allocate memory?

Comment: Yes, I want to copy to allocated memory key, which is input parameter

Comment: @Pavolmodrý Great. So do that!!!!! If your platform has `strdup`, you can use `(*tree)->key = strdup (key);`

Comment: so just by writing *tree->key = key .. I didnt copied it? do I understand it right?

Comment: @Pavolmodrý That sets `*tree->key` equal to `key`. Since `key` is a pointer, they now both point to the same place, which is not what you want. It couldn't possibly copy -- how would it know how many bytes to copy?

Comment: I allocated it just in case.. I was told every pointer should be allocated

Comment: @Pavolmodrý This is called [cargo cult programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cargo_cult_programming) and it will severely inhibit your learning and destroy your ability to code effectively. Do not do something unless you understand what it does and why you are doing it. Otherwise, you will do it even when it's inappropriate or even harmful.

Comment: is there any other way how to do it then by strdup?

Comment: @Pavolmodrý Sure, you can use `strcpy`. Just make sure you allocate enough memory. But honestly, it seems like you are attempting something way beyond your ability. You don't yet understand the basic use of pointers and how strings work in C. Is this your own code or are you trying to work on someone else's?

Comment: Yes youre right, I dont understand pointers very well, I tryed but its just too hard.. but I have this team project so I have to do it somehow